# node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/common.jsAttempted import error: 'requireNativeComponent' is not exported from 'react-native-web/dist/index'

Tags: react-native, native, linear-gradients

[Error in the Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6h4i.png)

[Code Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNXTh.png)

I've got trouble with the usage of linear-gradient in React-Native. I've installed everything right but this error always pops up. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the library you are using and use this library for linear gradient that is under react-native-community.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient